# Operations on certain tables won't finish

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g

We have a table TRANSMISSIONS(ID, NAME) which behaves funny in the following ways:

- The statement to add a foreign key in another table referencing TRANSMISSIONS.ID won't finish
- The statement to add a column to TRANSMISSIONS won't finish
- The statement to disable/drop a unique constraint won't finish
- The statement to disable/drop a trigger won't finish

TRANSMISSION's primary key is ID, there is also a unique constraint on NAME - therefore there are indexes on ID and NAME. We also have a trigger which creates values for column ID using a sequence, so that INSERT statements do not need to provide a value for ID.

Besides TRANSMISSIONS, there are two more tables behaving like this. For other tables, the above-mentioned statements work fine.

The database is used in an application with Hibernate and due to an incorrect JPA configuration we produced high values for ID during a time. Note that we use the trigger only for "manual" INSERT statements and that Hibernate produces ID values itself, also using the sequence.

The first thought was that the problems were due to the high IDs but we have the problems also with tables that never had such high IDs.

Anyways we suspected that the indexes might be fragmented somehow and called ALTER INDEX TRANSMISSIONS_PK SHRINK SPACE COMPACT, which ran through but showed no effect.

Also, we wanted to call ALTER TABLE TRANSMISSIONS SHRINK SPACE COMPACT which didn't work because we needed to call first ALTER TABLE TRANSMISSIONS ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT which never finished.

We have another instance of the database which does not behave in such a funny way. So we think it might be that in the course of running the application the database got somehow into an inconsistent state.

Does someone have any suggestions what might have gone out of control/into an inconsitent state?

More hints:

There are no locks present on any objects in the database (according to information in v$lock and v$locked_object)

We tried all these statements in SQL Developer and also using SQLPlus (command-line tool).

Comment: How many rows in the table? When was the last time statistics were collected on this table (`SELECT LAST_ANALYZED FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TRANSMISSIONS')`? Is there an index on the "other table" on the column referencing TRANSMISSIONS.ID?

Comment: Are these statements sitting there waiting for a commit?

Comment: Look for sessions that are blocking other sessions: `select * from gv$session where final_blocking_session is not null;`

Comment: @BobJarvis Currently about 20 rows. In the course of the table's lifetime there were at most 500 inserts. The "other table" was freshly created, so there is no index and in particular no values that would have to be checked against what is present in TRANSMISSIONS.ID...

**WPrecht-AB3RY** Since the ALTER TABLE statements (like adding a foreign key) have auto commit I'm not sure whether it takes so long to run the statement or whether it is the commit... Is there a way to find out?

The proposed statements I can only run on Tuesday, since I don't have access to the infrastructure during Easter

Comment: Adding a foreign to the "other" table requires that every row in the "other" table be checked to ensure that the existing values in the proposed foreign key also exist in TRANSMISSIONS. How many rows are there in the "other" table?

Comment: The other table - let's call it TRANSMISSIONGEARS - is newly created, i.e. `CREATE TABLE TRANSMISSIONGEARS` and then `ALTER TABLE TRANSMISSIONGEARS ADD CONSTRAINT ON TRM_ID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCING TRANSMISSIONS (ID)`. (The syntax is not 100% accurate.) So the new table does not have rows at all...

Comment: @JonHeller There is no session blocking sessions, your statement returns no rows.

Comment: While the slow statements are running, run this a few times to see what they are waiting for: `select event, gv$session.* from gv$session;`